# choices when implementing my own c++ matrix and vector class

Tags: c++, matrix

Recently, I need to implement a 4-dimensional matrix and vector class in C++ to assist my algorithm. It seems easy but I hesitate when I actually do these coding and I don't want to use `eigen` or `valarray`. Here are some of my confusions, they are more likely to be design problems rather than coding problems:

First. How to implement a column vector times a row vector(result in a matrix), should I define  two distinguish class like
    `class RVector4`
and
    `class CVector4`
inherit from the same `class Vector4` and then overload the operation "times" by the class on both sides or

should I define a single `class Vector4` and then define two distinguish operations: one "MTimes" to calculate colcumn vector times row vector and return a matrix, the other "VTimes" to calculate row vector times column vector and return a value?

Which is the convention or is more effective?

Second. Whether I should implement something like `class Matrix<int x, int y>` and just `typedef Vector4 Matrix4<4,1>` and `typedef Matrix4 Matrix<4,4>` if I just need to use 4-dimensional matrix and vector. In other word, define `Matrix<x,y>` and define `Matrix4` and 
`Vector4` separately, which is the better? And of course I need the operations like 
*Matrix4 * Vector4*, it `Matrix<x,y>` is over-coding?

Third. Are there some books talking about these questions? I always face these questions and feel annoyed.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "I don't want to use eigen or valarray" -- out of interest, why not ? Why re-invent the wheel ?

Comment: eigen really increases dependency and I suffered from valarray, i think valarray are used in numerical problems but my suituation isn't that complicated. And I really want to find the solutions to my confusions.

Comment: I'd almost say the answer to all the question is: It depends. For example the templated Matrix/Vector class is of course more powerful than a 4x4 only. But then it is more complicated to develop. It depends on your actual needs

Comment: At first I would avoid inheritance, prefer composition. Then you only need 3 classes, (4x4, 1x4, 4x1), see what can be factorized. you may  template way at helper class but it seems that interface of each have their own specialization...

Comment: eigen adds one dependency -- eigen. As a header-only library, it doesn't even complicate build; and you have all the source if there if necessary to tweak it, so you're not locked into someone else's bugs as in other libraries. And (as a developer not affiliated with the project) it's really, really good.

Comment: You can implement matrix alne and define horizontal vector as Matrix<1,4> using typedef

Comment: I also needed to write my own classes. I ended up with implementations of templated `vector3` `vector4` `matrix3x3` `matrix4x4` and scaling `vectorN` `matrixNxN` classes. However Im aware of the fact that external libs are much less errorprone and probably perform better. I wrote them to teach myself the fundamentals of the internal math and C++ constructs.